# Is it possible to search for all dependencies of a field

Tags: firebird, ibexpert

I am searching for a specific line in my database and wanted to know if there is a function in ibexpert to look up for all dependencies of a field.

Comment: What do you mean with "a specific line"? And exactly what do you want to find?

Comment: I am searching for a line of code which interacts with this field because I could not locate my problem until now. This field is changed in a procedure, view / trigger or whatever but I cannot find where exactly. I tried to use the tab "Dependencies" but that does not help me much,

Comment: `This field is changed in a procedure, view / trigger` why do you think so? it may be outside of Firebird. Like a crazy UDF making connection back to the DB and changing data. Or PSQL block may compose any program it likes then pass to `EXECUTE STATEMENT`. Or some OTHER firebird server may do remote connection. Well, my personal idea is, using IBExpert, to use "extract metadata" - and then dump all your database (except for data rows in your case) into a loooong textual file, SQL script. Then you load that text file into Notepad++ or anything and make search for the field name

Comment: you also can add CHECK-condition or a TRIGGER on that table, if you can formulate what is special about the change you want against all other changes. Then make that check/trigger generate some error (exception, division by zero, whatever) and then see where exactly your application would get busted

Comment: Ibexpert has a "Search in Metadata SHIT_ALT+F" which can search for Text entered. On the left pane you will see the objects, and on the right you can view the object source when selected.

Comment: @EdMendez thanks, this helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When field is selected in table click on "Field dependencies" tab.

[image]

Comment: I must have been blind. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know IBExpert, but generically in Firebird, you can find dependencies in the system table `RDB$DEPENDENCIES`. It won't tell you exactly on which line of code a field is used, but it will help you identify in what object it is used. Then it is a matter of inspecting the source code of that specific object to see where it's used.

The table `RDB$DEPENDENCIES` has the following columns (in Firebird 2.5):

- `RDB$DEPENDENT_NAME` - The name of the 'dependent' (the object using the dependency), eg a stored procedure name
- `RDB$DEPENDED_ON_NAME` - The name of the dependency (eg table name)
- `RDB$FIELD_NAME` - The field name of a dependency (eg table column); can be `NULL` for non-field dependencies
- `RDB$DEPENDENT_TYPE` - Type of the dependent (eg 0 = relation (table or view), see `RDB$TYPES` with `RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$OBJECT_TYPE` for possible values)
- `RDB$DEPENDED_ON_TYPE` - Type of the dependency (column dependencies have type 0 and `RDB$FIELD_NAME` not null, table/view dependencies have type 0 and `RDB$FIELD_NAME` null.

As an example, you can use the following query:

```sql
select dep.*, tt.RDB$TYPE_NAME as DEPENDENT_OBJECT_TYPE, dt.RDB$TYPE_NAME as DEPENDED_ON_OBJECT_TYPE
from RDB$DEPENDENCIES dep
inner join RDB$TYPES tt
  on tt.RDB$TYPE = dep.RDB$DEPENDENT_TYPE 
    and tt.RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$OBJECT_TYPE'
inner join RDB$TYPES dt
  on dt.RDB$TYPE = dep.RDB$DEPENDED_ON_TYPE 
    and dt.RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$OBJECT_TYPE'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will try this soon. My problem was solved with @Ed Mendez tip.
There I could find all tables / views / triggers in which I searched my field.